# Как обернуть функцию mysqli_stmt_bind_result?

Tags: php, ооп

Хочу обернуть функцию `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` в метод класса базы данных, но не могу додуматься до того, как сделать количество принимаемых методом аргументов - неограниченным.
Собственно, пробовал таким образом:

```
$param = func_get_args();
$refarg = [$this->_prepare];
foreach ($param as $key => $value):
    $refarg[] =& $param[$key];
endforeach;
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_result", $refarg);
```

**Обновление**

Накасячил я чутка с вопросом, обернуть нужно не bind_param, а bind_result,

По поводу `mysqli_stmt_bind result()` я бы так не сказал. Ее я обернул следующим образом:

```
public function bind(){
    $param = func_get_args();
    $refarg = array($this->_prepare, array_shift($param));
     foreach ($param as $key => $value):
        $refarg[] =& $param[$key];
    endforeach;
    call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", $refarg);
}
```

Передаю напрямую аргументы, без массива, и все работает как нужно, вот теперь хотелось бы найти похожее решение для `mysqli_stmt_bind_result();`

Comment: Что-то вы с названиями функций шалите.

Comment: И правда, только что заметил, сейчас исправлю

Comment: вероятно вы имеете в виду smpt?

Comment: я имел в виду mysqli_stmt_bind_result().Вопрос уже подкорректировал.

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев: `stmt` - вероятно от слова `statement`.

Answer (score 1):

У mysqli_stmt_bind_param есть особенность - крайние аргументы передаются по ссылкам. Но рекомендую попробовать вот так, должно сработать:

```
public function myMethod()
{
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $arguments);
}
```

У такой обертки будет один минус: она копирует в $arguments все полученные данные без возможности передавать ссылки на них. Но без этого никак.

Comment: пробовал я подобный способ, только несколько иной(описал выше).

Comment: Так опишите, какая возникает ошибка? Скорее всего, все дело в том, что выше уже написали Mik и Ипатьев. Метод `bind_param()` требует не массив элементов, а массив ссылок. Такая уж она, привередливая.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
function bind($stmt, $values)
{    
    $types = str_repeat("s", count($values));

    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0)
    {
        $bind = array();
        foreach($values as $key => $val)
        {
            $bind[$key] = &$values[$key];
        }

    } else {

        $bind = $values;
    }

    array_unshift($bind, $types);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Если делать неограниченное количество аргументов, то нет смысла оборачивать эту функцию куда-либо. Передавать надо **массив**. И тогда уже эту новую функцию-обертку можно будет использовать в окружении, когда количество передаваемых параметров неизвестно. Просто передавая массив.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.